# How to get ticks on the bottom subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting 8 subplots in a figure as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axs = plt.subplots(8,sharex="col" )
label = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
data = [0.6, 0.4, 1.3, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.6, 0.2]
plt.xlim(0,2)
for i in range(8):
    axs[i].set_xlim([0, 2])
    axs[i].axvline(data[i],linestyle='--')
    axs[i].set_yticks(())
    axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i], rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
axs[7].tick_params(axis='x', direction='out')
plt.show()
```

[image]

It all works fine except there are no ticks on the x-axis.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works fine for me on `matplotlib 2.2.2`. Perhaps try `sharex=True ` I don't see a reason why it is not working for you. Try restarting your kernel

Comment: Working for me on 3.0.2 also. Do you get the same with `agg` non-interactive backend (`import matplotlib; matplotlib.use('Agg')` before importing `pyplot` and then use `plt.savefig(filename)` instead of `plt.show()`? Wondering if it is your X display somehow causing a problem.

Comment: working with 3.1.3.

Comment: This is in Jupyter note book with %matplotlib qt. Can you reproduce that? @Sheldore

Comment: I tried qt in jupyter and it opens a figure in new window where I still all see the ticks

Comment: @Sheldore This is very odd. I just tried it from a normal python script and I get the ticks.  I will just run it from the command line instead.  How do I get the ticks only in the bottom subplot? Currently it has them in all the subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering your question in the comments. You can hide the ticks for all axes except the last one using the following

```
for i in range(8):
    axs[i].set_xlim([0, 2])
    axs[i].axvline(data[i],linestyle='--')
    axs[i].set_yticks(())
    axs[i].set_ylabel(label[i], rotation=0, ha='right', va='center')
    if i!=7:
        axs[i].tick_params(axis='x', direction='out', length=0) # Hide the ticks for all but last axis
        # axs[i].xaxis.set_tick_params(direction='out', length=0) # This is 2nd way to do
```

[image]